# XCFramework asking for instance of self when not specified

Tags: swift, xcode, xcframework

I'm trying to create a Framework that I can use across platforms. I have successfully added the framework to a test app and this is what the test framework looks like. Quite simple, all I want to do is import the framework and call `HelloComputer.getHello()` and get hello in return.

```
import Foundation

public class HelloComputer {

    public func getHello() -> String {

        return "hello world"

    }
}
```

But when I import the framework this is what happens

[image]

Am I missing something? Why is it asking for a instance of its self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `getHello()` as an instance method. Either call it like `HelloComputer().getHello()` or define it as a class method:

```swift
public class func getHello() -> String {
```